# need sata raid box/enclosure

Tags: sata, drive-enclosure

I would like to attach a sata enclosure for RAID 5 with 5-6 drives (6TB each) that can connect at 6.0 GB speed to my workstation. I don't want to use 
USB 3.0. I understand I may need to buy a card that will control the RAID.

I have seen 8 drive boxes that appear as two sets of drives to the server. Are there any enclosures that will treat all 5 drives as a single RAID 5 setup?

I would prefer to get a machine that communicates via eSata 6.0 GB. I don't mind controlling the raid via a card installed on my computer. I don't mind RAID 5 (I would keep a spare in my desk). I would spend up to $700 on the enclosure.
thanks

Comment: If you don't want to use USB, that pretty much limits you to Thunderbolt, eSATA, Fibre Channel, iSCSI, SFF-8088, and maybe one or two others.  Could you narrow things down a bit, by deciding if you want the RAID functionality to be handled by the enclosure or by the controlling computer, by giving a price range, and by deciding if you *really* want RAID 5 rather than RAID 6 (modern drives are large enough that there's a real risk of a second drive failing before the array finishes recovering from the failure of the first)?